# Magento 2.4.0 Issues using docker with MariaDB

Tags: magento2, docker, mariadb

Has anyone else encountered this error?
I am using docker-compose.yml file with mariadb:10 image.

```
Schema creation/updates:
Current version of RDBMS is not supported. Used Version: 10.5.5-MariaDB-1:10.5.5+maria~focal. Supported versions: MySQL-8, MySQL-5.7, MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue about your database version is lower so magento2.4 is minimum requirement of mariadb10.4.so please check below link may issue solve.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html